# Can't run Ghost blog on subdomain without port

Tags: apache, nginx, ghost-blog

I'm new to nginx, Ghost and managing servers and can't work out how to get ghost running without specifying to port `:2368`

http://blog.ingledow.co.uk:2368 works, but http://blog.ingledow.co.uk does not.

I have two sites on my digital ocean droplet with two .conf files in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.  These are `ghost.conf` and `ingledow.co.uk`

The directory `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` is empty, by the way.

#### Ghost's config.js

```
// ### Production
    // When running Ghost in the wild, use the production environment
    // Configure your URL and mail settings here
    production: {
        url: 'http://blog.ingledow.co.uk',
        mail: {},
        database: {
            client: 'sqlite3',
            connection: {
                filename: path.join(__dirname, '/content/data/ghost.db')
            },
            debug: false
        },
        server: {
            // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
            host: '146.185.179.133',
            // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
            port: '2368'
        }
    }
```

#### /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

#### /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/ghost.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name blog.ingledow.co.uk;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:2368;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }
}
```

Comment: by not work you mean what ? white page? 404? 502?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration seems to be ok, but I think that the host address in your `config.js` file  should be `127.0.0.1`.

```
server: {
        // Host to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        // Port to be passed to node's `net.Server#listen()`, for iisnode set this to `process.env.PORT`
        port: '2368'
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and it was because initially I had changed the Ghost config.js file to use my server's IP address and domain name, so that I could reach it via IP:2368 and domainname. Once that worked, I wanted to setup nginx to listen on port 80 and redirect to port 2368. However, once you have nginx setup, it will listen on port 80 at the server's IP, so you will want to redirect to Ghost, which should be set to the localhost address 127.0.0.1, not your server's IP, and the port should be 2368 (if it is not already). gl.